# How to refer to a CSS style using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In ASP.NET MVC I could define a textBox editor like this and give it a style.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notes[i].Notes, new { style = "width: 500px;" });
```

How can I move the style to the Site.css file and just refer to it from the code above?

```
.myStyle {
    width: 500px;
}
```

I tried this which compiles but doesn't seem to work:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notes[i].Notes, "myStyle");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to give it a `class` attribute for your CSS rule to match:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notes[i].Notes, new { @class = "myStyle" });
```

Note that the `@` in `@class` has no special meaning in ASP.NET MVC. It's simply there to turn `class`, a keyword in C#, into an identifier, so you can pass it in as a property and it'll compile.

Answer (score 1):

One word of explanation. Normally if you want to add attributes, e.g. readonly, you would type:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notes[i].Notes, new { readonly = "readonly" });
```

Notice there is no `@` in front of readonly. You have to put `@` in front of the class attribute, because it's a keyword in C#. If you do it in VB.NET you do not have to escape, because you define properties with a leading `.`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Notes[i].Notes, New With { .class = "myStyle" });
```

Comment: `New With`... another cool VB.NET language feature I learned today.